# Javascript DOM performances on big tables

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on a big table (~ 30 rows * 90 columns ) and this table has to be "infinite".

Currently, when the user scrolls, I'm removing X columns at the end/beginning and add X columns to the beginning/end. I use this javascript on mobile with Cordova, and it's an heavy solution.

I heard that it might be better to not remove/add columns but to rewrite the content in each td and recenter the scrollLeft for better performance.

So I'm asking, has anyone already tried these solutions and which one is the best? I really want to improve performances and add/remove columns takes a lot of performances and freezes sometimes the UI for a little while.

Comment: Here is a good article about it (is the methodology used in ionic): http://ionicframework.com/blog/collection-repeat/

Comment: Thanks, if I understood this article, the solution would be to refill the table instead of adding/removing columns. I'll try that!

Comment: if you want read some more, this is a performance to that approach, http://ionicframework.com/blog/collection-repeat-iteration-two/

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer, I'm the maintainer)

I built the most performant DOM table, you can display infinitely many cells/columns (only limited by chrome RAM of holding the rows), and it runs 60fps on any device.

https://github.com/gabrielpetersson/fast-grid

I have:

1. custom virtualization that reuses the DOM of the rows and columns and only changes the text
2. custom event loop that prioritizes filtering/sorting making sure it never drops a frame
3. no weird stuff. No forced reflows/layouts, no weird overly functional javascript, no react